# How to access XML structure in JCN

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I need to read this in an XML structure in java compute node, As of now I am able to do this by fetching individual elements child by child.

But how do I fetch all the elements at once in XML structure?

```java
int i = 0;
String[] Array = new String[api.getResponse().size()];

while(api.hasNext()) {
        Map<String, String> recInMap= api.getNext();
        xmlnscRoot.getLastChild().createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE,"Details",null); //Root tag
        xmlnscRoot.getLastChild().getLastChild().createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE,"ABCD",recInMap.get("ABCD"));
        xmlnscRoot.getLastChild().getLastChild().createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE,"EFGH",recInMap.get("EFGH"));
        xmlnscRoot.getLastChild().getLastChild().createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE,"IJKL",recInMap.get("IJKL"));
        .
        .
        .
        .
    Array[i]=(recInChar);//add(CurRecord);
    i=i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you want to do.

You must use XPath or JAXB (if you have a schema) to simplify all these kind of parsing

A quick example below :

```
MbElement localEnvRootElement= outAssembly.getLocalEnvironment().getRootElement();
MbXPath mbXPath = new MbXPath("Variables/message");
Object resultObj = variablesElem.evaluateXPath(mbXPath);
if (resultObj != null && resultObj instanceof List) {
    listElt = (List<MbElement>) resultObj;
}
```

Then all you need to do is loop on the List of MbElement (e.g : with a for each)
Note : this code will get all the element under $LocalEnv/Variables/Message path